# How to handle confirm popup with phantomjs + behat + mink

Tags: symfony, phantomjs, behat, travis-ci, mink

In my tests I use this step to confirm a javascript confirm popup:

```
/**
 * @when /^(?:|I )confirm the popup$/
 */
public function confirmPopup()
{
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();
}
```

This step work fine with selenium2 and chrome/firefox, but doesn't work with **phantomjs**.

How can I handle a confirm popup with phantomjs ?

for informations:

- symfony: 2.0.23
- behat: 2.4.6
- mink: 1.5.0
- Symfony2Extension: 1.0.2
- MinkExtension: 1.1.4
- MinkBrowserKitDriver: 1.1.0
- MinkSelenium2Driver: 1.1.0
- phamtomjs 1.9.1

behat.yml

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: "http://localhost:8000/app_test.php"
            default_session: selenium2
            selenium2:
                wd_host: "http://localhost:9876/wd/hub"
```

Thanks!

PS: Here the gist : https://gist.github.com/blazarecki/2888851

Comment: Are you using the native javascript "alert" or a cooked up one?

Comment: I use the native one.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out Benjamin? I've come across the same issue...

Comment: Not I didn't. I'll update the post if I find a solution.

Comment: How do you run your tests that include an alert at the mo then, via Selenium?

Comment: phantomjs --webdriver=9876 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
php -S localhost:8000 -t web > /dev/null 2>&1 and I update my post to add behat.yml config file.

Comment: hello @BenjaminLazarecki can you please update this topic? i tried above but it didn't work for me wondering if there is a better way to solve this now.

Answer (score 1):

`phantomjs` is a headless browser, therefore all dialogs are not show and cannot be interacted with. A solution is to rewrite `widnow.confirm` and `window.alert` with your own functions that return pre-defined values.

Since a scenario runs within the same driver, it is perfectly safe to overwrite native methods with pre-defined return values (you will not have a situation where you really need to see a window within the same scenario). Moreover, it is safe to call these step definitions multiple times within a single scenario to flip returned value.

```
/**
 * @When I accept confirmation dialogs
 */
public function acceptConfirmation() {
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript('window.confirm = function(){return true;}');
}

/**
 * @When I do not accept confirmation dialogs
 */
public function acceptNotConfirmation() {
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript('window.confirm = function(){return false;}');
}
```

Scenario example:

```
Scenario: Removal of something with confirmation dialog
Given I accept confirmation dialogs
And I click a ".mylink" element
And I wait for AJAX to finish
And I should not see a ".some-removed-element" element
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my "Selenium2Driver.php" with the following:

```
public function acceptAlert()
{
$this->wdSession->accept_alert();
}
```

This makes the accept_alert() available for the driver.

So in the script, you could do something line this to accept the alert.

$this->getSession()->getDriver()->acceptAlert();

Note that I'm using the RawMinkContext not the native MinkContext